# Error when installing angular-google-chart via bower

Tags: angularjs, google-visualization, bower

I want to use google-chart using https://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart/, but when I want to install it via `bower install angular-google-chart --save`, I got the following error:

```
$ bower install angular-google-chart --save
bower angular-google-chart#*    cached git://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart.git#0.0.11
bower angular-google-chart#*  validate 0.0.11 against git://github.com/angular-google-chart/angular-google-chart.git#*
bower angular#~1.2.9            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.2.29
bower angular#~1.2.9          validate 1.2.29 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#~1.2.9
bower angular#1.4.7             cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#1.4.7           validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#^1.3.0 || >1.4.0-beta.0           cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#^1.3.0 || >1.4.0-beta.0         validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.3.0 || >1.4.0-beta.0
bower angular#>= 1.0.8                          cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#>= 1.0.8                        validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#>= 1.0.8
bower angular#^1.4.0                            cached git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#1.4.7
bower angular#^1.4.0                          validate 1.4.7 against git://github.com/angular/bower-angular.git#^1.4.0
bower                                        ECONFLICT Unable to find suitable version for angular
```

Comment: The version of angular may not suit requirements for the angular-google-chart library, visit their site and confirm the requirements

Comment: in their bower, it said that  `"dependencies": {"angular": ">1.2.8"},`. My current angular is `1.4.7`. Should it be okay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple solution is to use the provided cdn which can be seen [here](http://angular-google-chart.github.io/angular-google-chart/docs/latest/guides/getting-started/)